# Mikrotik per-connection-classifier alternative in Linux iptables

Tags: linux, iptables, load-balancing, nat, ppc

I'm looking for equivalent functionality in Linux as Mikrotik `per-connection-classifier`. My case is to use for dynamic CGNAT with preserving public IP for each user (not random public IP for each connection).

Thanks,
Blažej

Answer (score 0):

You can do that combining iptables with ipset but I believe you would want to use nftables for this.
With jhash and vmap and update you can do just that.
A general example for creating cgnat with nftables can be seen at:
https://github.com/diorgesl/php-cgnat

Would look at:
https://wiki.nftables.org/wiki-nftables/index.php/Load_balancing

I am pretty sure that this:
https://habr.com/ru/post/501234/

is what you were looking for.

I have also written an example for the usage of jhash with a 4/5-tuple based load balancing.
You can simply change the jhash to calculate the hash with the srcip and then add it into a set or a flow table.